# How can I assign for each client that is actualy connected to my Blazor server app a seperate "Client-connection-number"?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

I have a Blazor Server app, where each client can connect to a selected remote production machine and read the datas of its PLC. The dll for the PLC connection, requires for each client a seperate "connection number". The connection of the relevant PLC will established via this device number, and it should be the same as long as a client is connected.

I have to give to each new connected client to my Blazor server app, the most possible small connection number. That means:
If the first client Client-1 connects it will get "1". The second client "2" the third client "3", the fourth client "4". If these four clients are online and when Client-1 signs out, the next client should get "1". That means the released device number of a disconnected client, should assigned to the new connected client.

How could I do that in Blazor server app? Sorry that I cannot share with you a draft code because really I have no Idea where I should program an algorithm, that has information about all clients.
I use IIS windows authentication in my project.

Answer (score 1):

With [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

1. Create a new class `ClientConnectionNumberManager` and [Inject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) as Singleton. This class is a helper to know free numbers.
2. Create a new class that contains your `ClientConnectionNumber`
   [Inject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that class as `scoped`. This class gets `ClientConnectionNumberManager` on constructor and figure out the number and also to release number on dispose.
3. Wherever you need `ClientConnectionNumber` get the class via [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Blazor Server DI ensures that each user (each connection) has their own scoped class.